# Kerberos tickets for Active Directory users appear in cache for NON-AD (local) Mac OS X users

Tags: windows, macos, authentication, kerberos

I have a Mac OS X (Mavericks) client machine bound to a Windows Server 2012 domain controller.

1 local Mac OS X user: david.

2 Active Directory users: jack & jill

When I log into Mac OS X as jill and open Ticket Viewer, I can see jill's ticket.

If I then log in as local (NON-AD) user 'david' and open Ticket Viewer, I can still see jill's ticket even though I'm currently logged into Mac OS X as david.

The project I'm working on requires (from code) that my client application consume a RESTful service on the Windows domain using Windows Authentication/Kerberos. When I grab the default ticket from code, the same thing happens. If I'm logged in as jill, I get her ticket. But if I'm logged in as david (not only a different user, but also not a user in Active Directory on the DC)... I still get jill's ticket.

Why am I seeing AD users' tickets in the credentials cache of NON-AD (local) Mac OS X users?

Comment: Could you please provide some useful insights on how you consume the services?

Comment: It's just a JSON-based RESTful service. I talk to it using standard Cocoa APIs (NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection, ...).

Comment: I only mentioned the code in order to show that it confirms what I'm seeing at a higher level (from the user's perspective). Both show that the credentials cache of a local (non-AD) Mac OS X user contains tickets of AD users who have recently logged into the Windows domain. The service consumption is secondary I think.

Comment: I'm new to Kerberos in general, so this may be totally normal/expected behavior. In either case, I guess I just need to understand the rationale.